# Setting instance variables in synchronized block in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, synchronization

I have a function that is synchronized, but it seems that I can't directly change the value of my instance variables in that block.

```
+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
@synchronized(self) {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];

        //This is not allowed
        something = @"hello";

        //This is allowed
        self.something = @"hello world!";

        return sharedInstance;
    }
}

return nil;
}
```

Why is this the case? I have a variable that I need to access directly (and I don't want to synthesize that variable). How do I get around this?

Comment: What do you mean, "isn't allowed"? Does that code not compile? Trigger an error in the runtime? Can you provide specifics of the crash if it crashes?

Comment: @Darren There's plenty wrong, starting with the fact that he's treating a class method like an instance method, and trying to set ivars before `-init` has been called.

Comment: @Kevin but in the case of singleton objects, class methods (which starts with a + ) is really the same as instance methods (with a -), correct?

Comment: No. The receiver of a class method is the class itself, and `self` in the class method is the class. With a singleton object, the receiver is still an instance, it just happens to be the only instance of the class. The primary difference between using class methods and using a singleton are the singleton can have instance variables and a class method cannot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change instance variables because this isn't an instance method. The value of `self` is, in fact, the class itself. Your line of code `self.something = @"hello world!"` won't work either. What you really want is `sharedInstance.something = @"hello world!"`, and that will only work if `something` is a property. Even better would be to set up the ivars in the init method.

Oh, and you have no business setting ivars in `+allocWithZone:` anyway. The object has not been initialized yet.

Assuming you're trying to create a singleton here (as that's what it looks like), you may want to read this [blog post](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=178) on singletons in Obj-C.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. Yes sharedInstance.something works in this case. I was actually just following this blog post in creating singleton: http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/05/21/using-the-singleton-pattern-in-objective-c/ Out of curiosity, why is it that the blog post that you linked to strongly discourage using the singleton pattern?

Comment: Singletons are fine. The issue is that the Apple sample code implements a singleton by enforcing the single-instance constraint instead of making it a convention. Having a `+sharedInstance` method is fine. Enforcing only a single instance is almost never useful. For example, `NSUserDefaults` is a singleton, but it doesn't prevent you from alloc/init'ing your own separate instance. Same thing with `NSFileManager`. Having an actual need to restrict this is so rare you'll probably never need to do it.